# RDD to Dataframe Spark Couchbase

Tags: apache-spark, couchbase, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have created an RDD from a NOSQL database and I want to convert the RDD to a data frame. I have tried many options but all result in errors.

```
    val df = sc.couchbaseQuery(test).map(_.value).collect().foreach(println)


{"accountStatus":"AccountOpen","custId":"140034"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountOpen","custId":"140385"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountClosed","subId":"10795","custId":"139698","subStatus":"Active"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountClosed","subId":"11364","custId":"140925","subStatus":"Paused"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountOpen","subId":"10413","custId":"138842","subStatus":"Active"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountOpen","subId":"10414","custId":"138842","subStatus":"Active"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountClosed","subId":"11314","custId":"140720","subStatus":"Paused"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountOpen","custId":"139166"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountClosed","subId":"10735","custId":"139558","subStatus":"Paused"}
{"accountStatus":"AccountOpen","custId":"139575"}
df: Unit = ()
```

I have tried adding .toDF() to the end of my code and also creating a schema and using createDataFrame but receive errors. Whats the best approach to converting the RDD to Dataframe?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// The schema is encoded in a string
val schemaString = "accountStatus subId custId subStatus"

// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fields)
```

//

```
val peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema)
```

Error

```
<console>:101: error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  (data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (Unit, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
       val peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema)
```

other

```
val df = sc.couchbaseQuery(test).map(_.value).toDF()
```

Error

```
<console>:93: error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject]
       val df1 = sc.couchbaseQuery(test).map(_.value).toDF()
                                                      ^
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Please post the stackTrace too !

Comment: errors are now added. Thanks Mark

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
val data = spark.sparkContext
  .couchbaseQuery(N1qlQuery.simple(q), bucket)
  .map(_.value.toString())

spark.read.json(data)
```

Spark infers the schema from the Couchbase JSON string itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are assigning `val df` to the result of the call to foreach, which is of type `Unit`.

Remove the call to collect and foreach and that should work:

```
// removed collect().foreach() here:
val df = sc.couchbaseQuery(test).map(_.value)
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// The schema is encoded in a string
val schemaString = "accountStatus subId custId subStatus"

// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fields)
val peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema)
```

For the second approach, I suspect that spark sql doesn't know how to deal with the couchbase client supplied JsonObject, so try mapping the value to a String, then use Spark sql to read the rdd as JSON

Comment: Thanks @ImDarrenG . I tried the above but I received an error. error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives